# Enum in SpEL for grails spring security annotation?

Tags: grails, enums, spring-security, annotations, spring-el

Assuming a grails (v2.3.x) custom class created and setup in a way that mimics the java way outlined by @JamesWatkins [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno), it is simple to annotate a method with a static string:

```
@Secured(["@mySecurityService.hasPermission('special')"])
public void doSpecialStuff() { ... }
```

But in an attempt to prevent hard-coding values, is it possible to replace `'special'` by  embedding a custom Enum (or similar) in the SpEL expression?

I have tried this:

```
@Secured(["@mySecurityService.hasPermission('{ T(com.example.MyConfig$MyEnum.SPECIAL) }')"])
public void doSpecialStuff() { ... }
```

but I keep getting an exception about the string not being a constant:

```
Expected '@mySecurityService.hasPermission('{ T(com.example.MyConfig$MyEnum.SPECIAL) }')' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the SpEL syntax is wrong. Remove the `'` and move the `.SPECIAL` outside the `T(...)`.

Further, `@Secured` doesn't support SpEL - as seen in the other post, you have to use `@PreAuthorize`.

I just wrote a quick test case, and this works fine...

```
public class TestHandler implements MessageHandler {

    public List<Message<?>> sentMessages = new ArrayList<Message<?>>();

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("@myAuth.hasPermission(T(foo.TestHandler$MyEnum).FOO.toString())")
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
        sentMessages.add(message);
    }

    public enum MyEnum {
        FOO("foo");

        private final String value;

        private MyEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class MyAuth {

        public boolean hasPermission(String foo) {
            return "foo".equals(foo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws the same error: ` Expected '@mySecurityService.hasPermission({ T(com.example.MyConfig$MyEnum).SPECIAL })' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String in @org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
 @ line 26, column 15.`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking at the bigger picture, just correcting your SpEL syntax error. Updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Thanks @gary-russell, but I should've used more than tags to indicate that I'm trying to do this in grails (v2.3.x) which does support SpEL with the `@Secured` tag (I'll edit my question).  Regardless, I tried using `@PreAuthorize` and got the same error message.  Looking at the [response from Burt Beckwith to this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508184/using-pre-post-spring-security-annotations-with-grails), it sounds like the grails spring-security plugin (v2.0-RC2) might not mimic the SpEL support avail via straight java.

Comment: OK; sorry - I am a java guy :-)